# How to use Rebus data bus attachments with Rebus.Async replies

Tags: c#, .net-core, rebus, rebus-azureservicebus

I'm using `Rebus.Async` to send a request. Upon receipt, the consumer replies with a large amount of data, which it uploads to Azure Blob Storage using `Rebus.AzureBlobs`.

The sender receives the reply and attempts to read the attachment. When this happens, Rebus throws an exception:

> No message context is available - did you try to open a data bus attachment for reading OUTSIDE of a message handler?

Of course I'm *intentionally* opening the attachment outside a message handler because I'm using `Rebus.Async`. However, it seems this isn't supported.

Is there a way to get data bus working with `Rebus.Async` replies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to simply pass along the attachment ID (the `Id` property from the `DataBusAttachment` returned from `CreateAttachment`), which you can then

```cs
var dataBus = bus.Advanced.DataBus;

using (var source = await dataBus.OpenRead(attachmentId))
{
    // do your thing :)
}
```